# Windows Bootcamp at Startup Manager

Tags: mac, windows, bootcamp, usb, startup

I recently formatted my Macbook Air 2013 to install Linux. There are currently no OS installed.

When booting into the Startup Manager with the Linux Boot USB, i see the Linux portion (EFI Boot) but I also see a “Windows” Bootcamp option which I have no idea where is coming from.

See screenshot. Any idea where this is coming from? I never tried to install Windows on this machine.

[image: Startup Manager screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "EFI Boot" label along with the external drive icon means `/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` file was found on a volume on the flash drive. If selected, the firmware will EFI boot and execute this file.

The "Windows" label along with the Windows icon, badged with the internal drive icon, means the firmware detected the ability to BIOS boot from the internal drive. If selected, the firmware will BIOS boot by loading the MBR (the first sector on the drive) into memory and executing the software on the loaded sector. The firmware does nothing to actually determined if Windows software is installed on the Mac or flash drive.

Usually, for a Linux install on a MacBook Air 2013, "EFI Boot" would be selected.

With Linux, either selection usually results in the Mac firmware bootloader booting to GRUB, which is also as bootloader.